# How am I computing $\int e^{x}\ln(1+e^{x})\,dx$ incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck on this problem.
**Problem** Evaluate $$\int e^{x} \ln (1+e^{x})$$
**Attempt**
Integration by Parts:
Let $u=\ln(1+e^x), \ dv = \int e^{x} \ dx$ and we have $\ du = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ and $v=e^x$

$$\int u \ dv= uv - \int v \ du$$

Thus $$I=\ln(1+e^x) e^x - \int e^x \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \ dx$$

On the second integral apply $u=1+e^x$ and $\ du = e^x \ dx$ and

$$\begin{split}
I&=\ln (1+e^x) e^x - \int \frac{u-1}{u} \ du \\
&= \ln (1+e^x) e^x - \int 1- \frac{1}{u} \ du
\end{split}$$ which simplifies to

$$I=\ln (1+e^x) e^x - x- \ln(|1+e^x|) +C $$

Comment: "I hope it's okay to write this on paper" - not really, please type out your work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting

$$\int 1 du = u +C$$

instead of

$$\int 1  = x +C$$

also, you should get

$$+\int \frac 1u du$$

instead of

$$-\int \frac 1u du.$$

Comment: Which is why having $du$ is so important!

Answer (score 0):

You should just let $u=1+e^x$, $du=e^x\,dx$

Then

\begin{eqnarray} \int e^{x}\ln(1+e^{x})dx&=&\int\ln(u)\,du \\
&=&u\ln(u)-u+c
\end{eqnarray}

and take it from there.

[image: Integration by parts, tabular method]

Answer (score 0):

For your calculation you made one step (at least) wrong 
$$
\int 1 \to u \neq x
$$
So note to keep the variable you are integrating over.

To be honest your approach is rather long.
$$
u = 1+\mathrm{e}^x\implies du = \mathrm{e}^xdx
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int \ln u \;du = u\ln u - u +c
$$
sub back in for $x$.

Comment: Indeed your approach is not shorter than the OP's one, both involving a substitution and an integration by part. Just that the order are different and you skipped the checking on integration by part.

Comment: @Chinny84 does the final answer come out as: 
$$I=\ln (1+e^x) e^x - 1 + e^{x} - \ln(|1+e^x|) +C $$

Comment: @JohnMa I agree. Though it quickly resolves to a "known" integral. When I wrote this answer I saw neither of the answers (yours and I think John), but I thought it would be far easier to approach it with this sub than going around the houses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are integrating with respect to $x$, it's nice that $d(1+e^x)=e^xdx$, you can see the integral as 
$$\begin{align}
\int\ln\left(1+e^x\right)e^xdx\; & =\;\int\ln\left(1+e^x\right)\,d\left(1+e^x\right)\\
&\;=\;\left(1+e^x\right)\ln\left(1+e^x\right)-\int\frac{\left(1+e^x\right)}{\left(1+e^x\right)}\,d\left(1+e^x\right)\\
\\
&\;=\;\ln\left(1+e^x\right)+e^x\left(\ln\left(1+e^x\right)-1\right)+C\,.
\end{align}$$
When you see the $\log$ of a function, it's good practice to check if the derivative of that function is laying around somewhere in the integrand, sometimes you can integrate with respect to it. Notice that the second step is just integration by parts on the $\log$ function to get the final result.